# SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access on codewars, cannot see how

Tags: c

i tried to write an edge case for my function that accesses the given constant array by reading it and defined by the function in its bounds, still the tests crash and i cannot figure out where i do wrong. When i leave my if function out of the function(i am missing my edge case) but codewars seems to accept the code without crashing.I also went through pythontutor with my code and it works without a problem. Please tell me where i am doing wrong, since i have been sitting on this the whole day.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int queue_time(const int *customers, int customers_length, int n)
{ 
  int totalt = 0;
  int *timelist = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  
  for(int i = 0; i < customers_length; i++)
    timelist[i] = 0;

  int i = 0;
  int c = 0;
  int x = 0;
  int lowestval = 0;
  int highestval = 0;

  if (n > customers_length)
  { 
    highestval = customers[i];

    for(i = 1; i < customers_length; i++)
    {                                           //for this if function it crashes
      if( customers[i] > highestval)
        highestval = customers[i];
    }

    return highestval;
  }

  while (c < customers_length) 
  {
    if (timelist[i] == 0)
    { 
      timelist[i] = customers[c]; 
      c++;                                           
    } 

    while ((i < n && i < customers_length)&& timelist[i] != 0)  
      i++;
    
    if(i == n || i == customers_length)                      
    {
      i = 0;
      lowestval = timelist[i];

      while (i < n && i < c)                        
      {
        if (lowestval > timelist[i] && lowestval != 0)
          lowestval = timelist[i];
        else if (lowestval == 0)
          lowestval = timelist[x];

        i++; 
        x++;
      }

      i = 0;
  
      while (i < n && i < customers_length)
      {
        timelist[i] -= lowestval;
        i++;
      }
    
      i = 0;
      totalt += lowestval;
    }
  }

  return totalt;
}

int main(void)
{
    queue_time((int []){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5, 50);
}
```

i tried to double check it if my i variable accesses the memory anywhere out of bounds but i did not find anything, i tried to write the needed array in a different format, as a pointer but it did not change anything either.
I also tried copying the integer into another one which i allocate with malloc by myself, still it gives me the same error, even though as i see it i am only trying to read the array in places where it is defined, which pythontutor also shows me.

The sample test it crashes with are:

```
Test(queue_time, should_pass_some_basic_tests)
{
    cr_assert_eq(queue_time(NULL, 0, 1), 0);
    cr_assert_eq(queue_time((int []){1, 2, 3, 4}, 4, 1), 10);
    cr_assert_eq(queue_time((int []){2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4}, 6, 2), 9);
    cr_assert_eq(queue_time((int []){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5, 100), 5);
}
```

Comment: What if `customers_length` > `n`?

Comment: it should proceed with the while loop below

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Also if you don't reset `x` before the inner `while` loop it seems it may eventually run over the length of `timelist`.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Tip: `calloc()` will zero out your memory, saving you a lot of hassle.

Comment: i tried to use pythontutor which visualizes it, i have never used a real debugger before, still with pythontutor it runs perfectly.

Comment: If you've got *undefined behaviour* then it could crash, or not! That's why debugging it can be tricky, and why learning to use a proper debugger can be an essential skill.

Comment: The absolute chaos of this indentation makes what you're trying to do here hard to follow, to say the least, but you might try and `assert()` that all of your array accesses are *strictly* within bounds.

Comment: The supplied example data makes `if (n > customers_length)` true, so the first loop will do its thing and it'll then return, leaking memory. Move the memory allocation and initialization to:  `if (n > customers_length) {...}` `int *timelist = calloc(n, sizeof *timelist);` and add `free(timelist);` before you `return` at the end of the function.

Comment: *"What if customers_length > n? – It should proceed with the while loop below"*. But you have allocated `n` elements for `timelist` and initialise `customers_length` of them.

Comment: What is the point of the code? There is no output.

Comment: i moved the block below the if (n > customers_length) but i still do get the same error

Comment: Note that you have memory leaks. `free(timelist);` is needed before both returns.

Comment: @tadman, Re "*Did run your code in a debugger*", That would require knowing the inputs for which it fails. The question is effectively asking for which inputs the code fails.

Comment: point of the code is to solve this cata https://www.codewars.com/kata/57b06f90e298a7b53d000a86/train/c
and to return the solution.

the for loop is starting at 1 because i already defined highestval as  customers[i] but it should also work if it starts at 0

Comment: @Felix What data have you provide it when it crashes? I can't see how the example data you've provided us with can make it crash. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/1xroKrM9d)

Comment: A tell us exactly which one of the data sets that makes it crash

Comment: i updated the question with the sample tests; unfortionatly it does not tell me on which test it crashes it just gives me "Test Crashed
Caught unexpected signal: SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access."

Comment: The real problem: `cr_assert_eq(queue_time(NULL, 0, 1), 0);`   - You need to add `if(customers == NULL) return 0;` first in your function. With that line added, all assertions pass. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/zKPcjen3n)

Comment: In one of those examples `customers_length > n` so you'll be breaking the memory allocation. You allocated `n` elements but initialise the greater number`.

Comment: @oh my god thank you very much the if(customers == NULL)  worked. Thanks a lot guys, you were very helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome! An alternative check:  `if(customers_length == 0) return 0;` - or both: `if(customers == NULL || customers_length == 0) return 0;`